# I keep getting this error "The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher."

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I have been getting this error when trying to test my Flutter code of an APK for reading PDF files. How do I update the kotlin plugin version?

Here is my current version in gradle.build. I keep getting this error even though I am using a higher version of gradle.build.

Answer (score 2):

Change ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22' (or the latest Kotlin version, find it here : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details) in android/build.gradle file.

If you still get the error even after updating the kotlin version, try doing a flutter clean and run it again.